# How to save the Krusader Password and Bookmarks

Tags: 12.04, password, bookmarks, konsole, krusader

Im using Ubuntu 12.04 on my system and I need to reinstall the OS because of some graphical problems. So i need to make a backup of all the Bookmarks and Wallet Passwords of Krusader .

And also I need to save the Bookmarks of Konsole

But I found no option to save passwords and BM in both Konsole and Krusader.

And if backup succeeded then how to restore them after OS installation??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is assuming you're using the KDE desktop environment.

- According to the [Krusader documentation](http://www.krusader.org/documentation/config_files.html) the bookmarks are stored in a `krbookmarks.xml` file located in:

  `~/.kde/share/apps/krusader/krbookmarks.xml` where `~/` is your Home directory.
- According to this [Launchpad Answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/144526) the Konsole bookmarks are
  located in:

  `~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/bookmarks.xml`
- According to this *old* [Forum Post](http://nixforums.org/about25787-Backing-up-Kwallet.html) Kwallet stores it's password in:

  `~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet/kdewallet.kwl`

  Although this is an old forum post but I assume the location hasn't changed as it fits in with the general location scheme used by Krusader, Konsole and other KDE apps.

In order to restore these files after a fresh install you should follow these steps:

1. Backup the files to an external HDD/USB or even a partition on your computer that won't be formatted. (I dual boot so I place files I want to keep onto the Windows partition during the re-installation of Ubuntu.)
2. Proceed with the re-installation of Ubuntu.
3. Re-install the necessary applications (KDE/Krusader/Konsole/Kwallet Manager).
4. Copy the relevant files back to the relevant locations as listed at the start of this answer.

Comment: Yes, I copied complete kde folder and lets hope it will work after installation

Comment: Be careful with copying the full folder, I did it before with Cinnamon and it messed up my theme after restoring the folder on a fresh install.

Comment: sorry for late reply, But just to let you know that it worked.

Comment: Good to hear :).